# Inputting your name with java

Tags: java, input

Ok so im trying to create one of the oldschool rpg character input screens. I have a graphic 
with all of the letters on it and what i'd like to do is have it when the user clicks on a 
letter it sets that letter to the first value of a string, if they click on another letter it 
sets it to the second value of the string and so on (8 chars maximum). Clicking on the
backspace will of course, delete the last letter inputted.

Is there an easy way to do this? aside from say, creating a variable for each char inputted for all 8 chars and adding them together and making checks for each one

Edit - Added the code i've got so far. I've changed this from trying to do it with a bunch of variables *one for each char of the name* to using stringbuilder, but now it crashes when i try to delete the last letter.

So far as a test i only have the clicking on a and clicking on backspace checks there

```
package states;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

import tools.FontFactory;
import tools.ResourceManager;

public class NameState extends BasicGameState {


private UnicodeFont font = null;

Image ename;
public String mouse = "No input yet!";

String namechar = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public int getID() {
    return Globals.STATE_NAME;
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game)
        throws SlickException {
    font = FontFactory.createFontL(ResourceManager.getFont("visitor")
            .getFontFile(), java.awt.Color.WHITE);

    ename = new Image("resources/graphics/entername.png");

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {
    g.setFont(font);
    ename.draw(0, 0);
    g.drawString(namechar + sb.toString(), 130, 40);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)
        throws SlickException {

    int xpos = Mouse.getX();
    int ypos = Mouse.getY();

    mouse = "Mouse position x: " + xpos + " y: " + ypos
            + "\nTrue Cords     x: " + xpos + " y: " + ((ypos - 480) * -1);

    if (namer == 1) {

        if ((xpos > 121 && xpos < 155) && (ypos > 278 && ypos < 318)) { if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                sb.append("A"); namer = 2; } } }

    if (namer == 2) {

        if ((xpos > 121 && xpos < 155) && (ypos > 278 && ypos < 318)) { if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                sb.append("A"); namer = 3; } } }


    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 2) { sb.setLength(0); namer = 1;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 3) { sb.setLength(1); namer = 2;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 4) { sb.setLength(2); namer = 3;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 5) { sb.setLength(3); namer = 4;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 6) { sb.setLength(4); namer = 5;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 7) { sb.setLength(5); namer = 6;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 8) { sb.setLength(6); namer = 7;  } } }
    if ((xpos > 650 && xpos < 700) && (ypos > 62 && ypos < 96)) {
        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) { if (namer == 9) { sb.setLength(7);namer = 9;   } } }
}
```

}

Comment: please explain what you have tried so far and where you are hitting the wall.

Comment: And how does this relate to `slick`?

Comment: Java, not javascript.

And i've tried making a variable for each of the 8 characters and tried setting letters to them and setting the variables to "" when you click on the backspace but this seems like an awfully horrible way to go about it

Sorry using slick2d, its extending a basicgamestate

Comment: Well, show your code please (edit the question, don’t past it in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Javadoc for setLength](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength%28int%29) you’ll see that the argument must be non-negative. This method sets the length of the `StringBuilder` to the specified length. So, if you want to decrement the length by 1, you need to do:

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
```

Note that this code will crash if the `StringBuilder` is empty. So you may want to add a check:

```
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Dont suppose you could tell me how i can get it to just click once? i think i figured out my first problem but now when i click once on a letter it clicks more than once

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t help you on this. You should ask it in another post.